# Bash Command Not Found Error with $variable

Tags: bash, command-not-found

```
108   ps --ppid $process | while read -r line ; do
109      #echo $line | awk '{print $1;}
110      child=$($line | awk '{print $1;}')
111      echo $child
113   done
```

Running this code gives me the following error:

```
line 111: 3405: command not found
```

But if I uncomment line 109 it prints the correct value without an error

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?  without the `echo` `$line` will be treated as a command to run, apparently the command `3405` in your example.

Comment: This smacks of an XY problem to me, what is it that you're actually trying to do?

Comment: line 110 looks fishy to me (did you mean to 'echo $line' to awk?)

Comment: Post [complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain what you want the script to do.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're not actually giving the value in `$line` to `awk`.  Instead you try to execute it as a command.

If all you want to do is output the child processes of a process with a certain  PID, then you don't need to loop:

```
ps --ppid "$process" -o pid=
```

This would get the list of processes that has `$process` as their PPID, and for each output their PID.

Also related:

- [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716)

Answer (score 0):

Fix it...

```
ps --ppid $process | while read -r line ; do
  child=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
done
```